# Kotlin RecyclerView, having issue with loading the items into the recyclerview

Tags: android, oracle, kotlin, android-recyclerview

---

so currently i'm using this code to get the data from oracle and save it into a data class and from the data class i put it in the recyclercview using the adapter here are the parts of the code,

```
Adapter:\package com.example.mobileappv2
import android.view.LayoutInflaterimport android.view.Viewimport android.view.ViewGroupimport android.widget.Buttonimport android.widget.TextViewimport androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerViewimport com.example.mobileappv2.ui.dashboard.scannedCodes

class FoodMenuAdapter(private val menuItems: ArrayList<BookRecord>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodMenuAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    // Define properties for each view in your custom layout
    val ItemNum: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ItemNum)
    val ItemDescription: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ItemDescription)
    val OPNum: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.OPNum)
    val LotNumber: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.LotNumber)
    val PickQuantity: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.PickQuantity)
    val StockLocation: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.StockLocation)
    val PcsMissing: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.PcsMissing)
    val buttonPL: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonPL)

}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    // Inflate the custom layout for the food menu item
    val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.picklistsetup, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(itemView)

}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val menuItem = menuItems[position]

    // Set the data from the current item to the respective views
    holder.ItemNum.text = menuItem.item
    holder.ItemDescription.text = menuItem.description
    holder.OPNum.text = menuItem.OPNum
    holder.LotNumber.text = menuItem.LotNumber
    holder.PickQuantity.text = menuItem.PickQuantity
    holder.StockLocation.text = menuItem.StockLocation
    holder.PcsMissing.text = menuItem.PcsMissing

    // Set click listener for the button
    holder.buttonPL.setOnClickListener {

        val bookingID = menuItem.bookingId
        scannedCodes.add(bookingID.toString())

    }

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {

    return menuItems.size

}

}
```

Layout for the recycler view:

```
\<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"android:layout_width="match_parent"android:layout_height="wrap_content"tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ItemDescription"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ItemNum"
            tools:ignore="TextSizeCheck" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/LotNumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/OPNum" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/StockLocation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/PickQuantity" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/PcsMissing"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/StockLocation" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/OPNum"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ItemDescription" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ItemNum"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/PickQuantity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/LotNumber" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text="Pcs Missing:"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text="Lot Number:"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text="Pick Quantity:"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text="Stock Locator:"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonPL"
            android:layout_width="181dp"
            android:layout_height="59dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
            android:text="Scan and Book"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/PcsMissing" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:text="Item Number:"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text="Item Description:"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text="OP Number:"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Layout in which the recyclerview is in:

`````
`\<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"android:layout_width="match_parent"android:layout_height="match_parent"tools:context=".ui.notifications.NotificationsFragment">
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_notifications"
    android:layout_width="0sp"
    android:layout_height="0sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

```
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`
````
`````

---

calling the adapter from the recyclerview fragment:

````
***

```
\package com.example.mobileappv2.ui.notifications
```

```
import android.os.Bundleimport android.view.LayoutInflaterimport android.view.Viewimport android.view.ViewGroupimport android.widget.TextViewimport androidx.fragment.app.Fragmentimport androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviderimport androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManagerimport androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerViewimport com.example.mobileappv2.BookRecordimport com.example.mobileappv2.FoodMenuAdapterimport com.example.mobileappv2.databinding.FragmentNotificationsBinding
```

```
class NotificationsFragment : Fragment() {
```

```
private var _binding: FragmentNotificationsBinding? = null

// This property is only valid between onCreateView and
// onDestroyView.
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val notificationsViewModel =
        ViewModelProvider(this).get(NotificationsViewModel::class.java)

    _binding = FragmentNotificationsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val root: View = binding.root

    val textView: TextView = binding.textNotifications
    notificationsViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        textView.text = it
    }

    val recyclerView: RecyclerView = binding.recyclerView
    val menuItems = ArrayList<BookRecord>()
    val adapter = FoodMenuAdapter(menuItems)
    val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false) // Set the layout manager
    layoutManager.scrollToPosition(0)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter

    return root
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
```

```
}``
```
````

getting the data from the home page:

````
  import android.annotation.SuppressLintimport android.os.Bundleimport android.view.LayoutInflaterimport android.view.Viewimport android.view.ViewGroupimport android.widget.EditTextimport android.widget.TextViewimport android.widget.Toastimport androidx.fragment.app.Fragmentimport androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviderimport com.example.mobileappv2.BookRecordimport com.example.mobileappv2.Rimport com.example.mobileappv2.bookRecordsimport com.example.mobileappv2.databinding.FragmentHomeBindingimport org.jsoup.Jsoupimport org.jsoup.parser.Parserimport java.io.BufferedReaderimport java.io.InputStreamReaderimport java.net.HttpURLConnectionimport java.net.URL
  
      private val Picklist = mutableListOf<String>()private const val PhoneLocation = "MAIN STORES"
  
      class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
      private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
      
      // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
      // onDestroyView.
      private val binding get() = _binding!!
      
      override fun onCreateView(
          inflater: LayoutInflater,
          container: ViewGroup?,
          savedInstanceState: Bundle?
      ): View {
          val homeViewModel =
              ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
      
          _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
          val root: View = binding.root
      
          val textView: TextView = binding.textHome
          homeViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
              textView.text = it
          }
      
          val sendbutton = binding.sendButton
          sendbutton.setOnClickListener{
      
              sendPinandjobnumber()
      
          }
      
          return root
      }
      
      @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
      private fun sendPinandjobnumber() {
          val navHome = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null)
          val test = navHome.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.test)
      
          val jobnum = binding.root.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.JOBNum).text
          Picklist.add(jobnum.toString())
          val pin = binding.root.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.PINNum).text
          Picklist.add(pin.toString())
          Picklist.add(PhoneLocation)
      
          if (Picklist.isNotEmpty()) {
              Thread {
                  try {
      
                      // HTTP POST request to send the data to the php
                      val url = URL("Used to connect to the oracle database")
                      val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
      
                      connection.requestMethod = "POST"
                      connection.doOutput = true
      
                      val postData = "data=${Picklist.joinToString(",")}"
                      val writer = connection.outputStream.bufferedWriter()
                      writer.write(postData)
                      writer.flush()
      
                      val responseCode = connection.responseCode
      
                      if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                          // Read the response from the php
                          val inputStream = connection.inputStream
                          val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))
                          val response = bufferedReader.readLine()
      
                          requireActivity().runOnUiThread() {
      
                              test.text = Picklist.toString()
      
                              Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Data was sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
      
                              val xmlDoc = Jsoup.parse(response, "", Parser.xmlParser())
                              val recordElements = xmlDoc.select("BOOKRECORD")
                              for (recordElement in recordElements) {
      
                                  val bookingId = recordElement.selectFirst("BOOKING_ID")?.text()
                                  val ItemNum = recordElement.selectFirst("ITEM")?.text()
                                  val ItemDescription = recordElement.selectFirst("DESCRIPTION")?.text()
                                  val OPNum = recordElement.selectFirst("UOM")?.text()
                                  val LotNumber = recordElement.selectFirst("LOT_NUMBER")?.text()
                                  val PickQuantity = recordElement.selectFirst("OPENQTY")?.text()
                                  val StockLocation = recordElement.selectFirst("STOCKLOCATOR")?.text()
                                  val PcsMissing = recordElement.selectFirst("MISSING")?.text()
      
                                  val bookRecord = BookRecord(bookingId, ItemNum, ItemDescription, OPNum, LotNumber, PickQuantity, StockLocation, PcsMissing)
                                  bookRecords.add(bookRecord)
      
                              }
      
                          }
      
                      } else {
                          val errorMessage = "HTTP error: ${connection.responseMessage}"
                          requireActivity().runOnUiThread {
      
                              Toast.makeText(
                                  requireContext(),
                                  errorMessage,
                                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                              ).show()
      
                          }
                      }
                  }
                  catch (e: Exception) {
                      val errorMessage = "Error: ${e.message}"
                      requireActivity().runOnUiThread {
      
                          Toast.makeText(requireContext(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
      
                      }
                  }
              }.start()
          }
      }
      
      override fun onDestroyView() {
          super.onDestroyView()
          _binding = null
      }
      }```


i tried moving the call for the adapter and such from one fragment to another and to the main activity aswell and i even put toasts to make sure everything was loading and such i don't get any errors when i go to the notification fragment and sadly i don't get the list either
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sincerly, I never put RecyclerView logic in `onCreateView()` since it's only responsible to get the binding and inflate your layout.

Try moving all the logic for RecyclerView from `onCreateView()` to `onViewCreated()`.

Binding is also accessible in `onViewCreated()`.

Didn't tested but you should have something like this:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val homeViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)

    val textView: TextView = binding.textHome
    homeViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        textView.text = it
    }

    val sendbutton = binding.sendButton
    sendbutton.setOnClickListener{
        sendPinandjobnumber()
    }
}
```

Let me know if this solved your problem, if not, comment and I will provide more support, happy coding!